# How do I show convergence of a specific series over the ring of 2-adic integers?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, p-adic-number-theory

This question is somehow quite similar to the one posted here: [How do I show convergence in the 2-adics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349310/how-do-i-show-convergence-in-the-2-adics) by "it's a hire car baby". We know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} p^n=0$ (proof in [https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2020/REUPapers/Pomerantz.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2020/REUPapers/Pomerantz.pdf), page 5).
We also know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^nA_n \right)$ converges over the 2-adics if and only if $A_n{\to}0_2$ when ${n\to\infty}$.

Now we have that $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n3^{-k}2^{\sum_{k=0}^nv_2(f_k)} \right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n(3^{-k}\prod_{k=0}^n2^{v_2(f_k)}) \right)$ , where $x$ is any odd 2-adic positive integer, $f_{k+1}(x)=(3f_k / 2^{v_2(f_k)}) + 1$ , $f_0 = 3x +1$ , $v_2(f_k)$ would be the 2-adic valuation of $f_k$, and $L$ must be a positive integer, by condition.

As $x$ is an odd positive integer, we notice that $v_2(f_k) \geq 1$

Given all the conditions above, would it be accurate to say that $L$ converges over the ring of the 2-adic integers? If it does, would it be possible to calculate the value of $L$, even if it was dependant of $x$ (which I guess it might be)?

Thank you in advance for reading. Any comment will be much appreciated.

Comment: "We know that $\infty_p=\lim_{n\to\infty} p^n$ and that $\infty_2=0_2$". I do not know that. I do not know what it means.

Comment: "$v_k(f)$ would be the 2-adic valuation of $f_k$". Then why not denote it by $v_2(f_k)$ so other people can understand it? --- If you want to be understood, use standard notation!

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thank you very much for the corrections. I'm new to this forum and the TeX commands, so your comments helped me a lot. I've edited them now to the hope they fit the standard notation. I've also added a reference to the proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty} p^2=0_2$

Comment: You might mean that $\lim_{n\to \infty} p^n = 0$ in $p$-adics (which does not need a proof for people who have heard of $p$-adics). Both $2$'s in your $\lim_{n\to \infty} p^2 = 0_2$ are nonsensical, for different reasons.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg once again, thank you very much for your corrections. I've edited the post regarding your directions and added another expression for L. Hope it's clearer now